# TextView onClickListener does not recognize the click

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin, textview

Basically, I have a layout with an EditTex with multiline input type and a clickable `TextView`. The problem comes when I click the `TextView` It seems that setOnClcickListener isn't working properly.

The debugger of the code shows that the listener doesn't recognize the click.

Activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/reviewText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.069" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/submitReviewTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:text="Enviar Crítica"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.974"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/reviewText"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.575" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the Activity code:

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var reviewConditionsOk = true

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        submitReviewTextView.setOnClickListener {
            checkMandatoryReviewConditions()
            if (!reviewText.text.isEmpty() && !reviewConditionsOk) {
                Log.d("Test", "Button Clicked")
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,
                    "La crítica no a de estar vacía y tiene que tener un mínimo de 5 líneas.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed()
        finish()
    }

    private fun checkMandatoryReviewConditions() {
        reviewText.onFocusChangeListener = View.OnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
            if (hasFocus) {
                reviewConditionsOk = reviewText.text.toString().trim().length < 5
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this method `checkMandatoryReviewConditions()` just returns after setting a new `View.OnFocusChangeListener` on the `EditText` and doesn't change this `reviewConditionsOk` instance variable, so this condition `!reviewConditionsOk` is never met. You can confirm this with logging as the first line of the click listener, before any logic ..

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code along with the code myself and found no problem with the click listener. The event is triggered correctly. You need to modify the following condition so that it shows the `Toast` that you want to get.

```
if (!reviewText.text.isEmpty() && !reviewConditionsOk) // Fix this
```